# get double running when pressing gesture handler in flutter

Tags: flutter, click

Hi I have a row that contains 2 containers, and in each container, I wrap it using GestureDetector, but the problem is.. whenever I click first container... the second container always do the same thing at **the same time** like first container do, before I click the second container.. Here is the code

```
 Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: fail
                  ? () {
                      setState(() {
                        out=false;
                      });
                      _getData();
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Container(...)
            ),
           GestureDetector(
              onTap: failOut
                  ? () {
                      setState(() {
                        out=true;
                      });
                      _getData();
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Container(...)
            )
)
```

is there something that I miss here?

Comment: fail and failOut are the same?

Comment: yes, both of them are same.. I only make different variable just to differentiate between first container and second container

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem (row with 2 containers wrapped in gesture detectors) and all worked fine each detector only detected its own events


are you sure there is nothing wrong with your screen which is capturing the events?

Comment: is your code also calling the same function?.. I mean I call _getData(); function inside first container and second container

Comment: calling the function is irrelevant,the problem, if exists, will be that the 2 detectors are detecting the gesture simultaneously and the function has nothing to do with this as far as I know

Comment: I just get my mistake... it is because I am doing wrong when setting state for second container.. I forget to recheck.. and... thanks for your help :D